# ¿Por que el calculo matematico sale mal en SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Por que la suma es erronea? tengo el siguiente Script de SQL SERVER

```
DECLARE 
@UserUID INT,
@CharID INT = 1

CREATE table #temp (CharID INT, ItemID INT, Count INT);
CREATE table #temp2 (UserUID INT,CharID INT, ItemID INT, Count INT);

INSERT INTO #temp(CharID, ItemID ,Count)VALUES
(1,1001,15),
(1,1001,5),
(1,1001,5),
(1,1001,5),
(31,1001,5),
(31,1001,5),
(4,1001,5),
(2,1001,5);

INSERT INTO #temp2(UserUID, CharID, ItemID ,Count)VALUES
(6,1,1001,20),
(6,1,1001,5),
(6,1,1001,5),
(6,1,1001,5),
(6,1,1001,5),
(66,31,1001,5),
(66,31,1001,5),
(8,2,1001,5);

SET @UserUID =(SELECT TOP 1 UserUID FROM #temp2 WHERE CharID = @CharID)

SELECT
SUM(a.Count)AS COl_A,
SUM(b.Count)AS Col_B
,sum(a.Count) + SUM(b.Count)as Col_C
FROM #Temp a
INNER JOIN #Temp2 b
ON a.CharID = b.CharID
WHERE a.CharID = @CharID 
AND b.UserUID =@UserUID

DROP TABLE #Temp
DROP TABLE #Temp2
```

me da como resultado

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
+-------+-------+-------+
|  150  |  160  |  310  |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Pero deberia ser:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
+-------+-------+-------+
|  30   |   40  |  70   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la columna CharID no es única en ninguna de las tablas, por lo que se hace un producto cartesiano al unir las dos tablas por esa columna. Si eliminamos las funciones de agregado, se vuelve evidente.

```
SELECT a.Count, 
       b.Count
FROM #Temp a
INNER JOIN #Temp2 b ON a.CharID = b.CharID
WHERE a.CharID = @CharID 
AND b.UserUID =@UserUID;
```

Genera el siguiente resultado:

```
Count       Count
----------- -----------
15          20
5           20
5           20
5           20
15          5
5           5
5           5
5           5
15          5
5           5
5           5
5           5
15          5
5           5
5           5
5           5
15          5
5           5
5           5
5           5
```

Para evitar la duplicación de valores, es importante hacer la sumatoria antes de unir las tablas para que la relación siempre sea uno a uno.

```
WITH cteTempAgg AS(
    SELECT CharID,
           SUM( Count) AS Col_A
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE CharID = @CharID
    GROUP BY CharID
),
cteTemp2Agg AS(
    SELECT CharID,
           SUM( Count) AS Col_B
    FROM #Temp2
    WHERE CharID = @CharID
    AND UserUID  = @UserUID
    GROUP BY CharID
)
SELECT  t1.Col_A,
        t2.Col_B,
        t1.Col_A + t2.Col_B AS Col_C
FROM cteTempAgg t1
JOIN cteTemp2Agg t2 ON t1.CharID = t2.CharID
```

En este caso, podría omitir la columna CharID y solo unir las tablas con un `CROSS JOIN`, pero prefiero dejarlo así para permitir que se pueda mostrar más de un valor de esa columna.